# Supporting SEF URLs in custom component

Tags: joomla-3.x, sef

In Joomla! documentation it is stated that:

> Since Joomla 3.3, one should rather implement the interface                 JComponentRouterInterface and handle the routing and parsing similar as below, but via the methods of this interface.

But I cannot find any sample implementation of the interface mentioned above. Can anyone provide an example?

https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the old days, the `router.php` file contained functions: `BuildRoute` and `ParseRoute`. Nowadays, if you look at the `router.php` of the `banners` extension for example, you will see a class called `BannersRouter` which extends from `JComponentRouterBase`, and within that class you will see the `build` and the `parse` functions. Additionally, just immediately after the class, you will also see the `bannersBuildRoute` and the `bannersParseRoute` functions (these 2 functions are necessary and will invoke the `build` and the `parse` methods).

So, in your `router.php`, once you use a class that extends from `JComponentRouterBase` (like the banners component), instead of just using `BuildRoute` and `ParseRoute`, then you are automatically implementing the `JComponentRouterInterface` in your component.

Hope this helps!